# Rails 4.1 500 Internal Server Error in production apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

My problem:
I have VPS with apache. One of project in Rails 3.2 work in production in this VPS.
Now, I have a projiect with Rails 4.1. In develovepment mode all work in this VPS. But, when I start project in production mode, I have error:

```
 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at saifon.rubyserv.ru Port 80

bundle exec rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:schema:load 
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

production:
adapter: postgresql
host: localhost
port: 5432
database: ###
username: ###
password: ##
pool: 5
timeout: 10000
```

environments/develovepment.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.assets.precompile += ['admin/application.js']
  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

And config Apache:

```
DocumentRoot /home/###/public
  ErrorLog /home/###/log/production.log
  CustomLog /home/###/log/production.log combined
  RailsEnv production
  <Directory /home/###/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </directory>
<Location /assets/>
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: "rake secret" and add this key to "secret.yml"

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentRoot and Directory should point to the path where your application is kept.

```
ex. DocumentRoot /home/your_project/public
```

Comment: Yes, I have DocumentRoot /home/your_project/public. if "production" exchange to "develovepment" all work.